# langRestrict=en doesn't return any values anymore

Tags: google-books-api

I used to use queries like this when searching:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0590353403&langRestrict=en&maxResults=5&printType=books&showPreorders=false&fields=items(volumeInfo(authors,imageLinks,pageCount,title,industryIdentifiers))

Recently however, it seems that using `langRestrict=en` no longer return results.  If I remove that, it works again.

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0590353403&maxResults=5&printType=books&showPreorders=false&fields=items(volumeInfo(authors,imageLinks,pageCount,title,industryIdentifiers))

If I look at the book in question, the language is listed as `language="un"` now:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0590353403

Can anyone explain what changed, and should I be using `langRestrict=un` instead? (What language is `un`? I can't seem to find information on it.) Thank you.

Comment: "un" is definitely not a valid ISO 639-1 language code (which is what `langRestrict` theoretically uses)... however I'd assume that means "undetermined" in that context, which does have an official ISO 639-2 code (which is "und"). I'd assume someone messed up in the API at google :-)